# Do subgroup invocation indices map to gl_LocalInvocationIndex?

Tags: vulkan

Do I need to calculate `gl_SubgroupID*gl_SubgroupSize+gl_SubgroupInvocationID`, or can I use `gl_LocalInvocationIndex`? Are invocations within a single subgroup consecutive in `gl_SubgroupInvocationID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to calculate `gl_SubgroupID*gl_SubgroupSize+gl_SubgroupInvocationID`, or can I use `gl_LocalInvocationIndex`?

These are different things. The local invocation index is the index of an invocation within a work group. Subgroups are groupings of invocations that are no larger than a work group, but may be *smaller*. As such, subgroup invocation index is not the same as the local invocation index.

As the standard puts it:

> There is no direct relationship between `SubgroupLocalInvocationId` and `LocalInvocationId` or `LocalInvocationIndex`.

---

> Are invocations within a single subgroup consecutive in `gl_SubgroupInvocationID`?

Yes, they are consecutive, but only in the sense that they will be on the half-open range [0, `SubgroupSize`). So two invocations that may have adjacent local invocation indices may not have adjacent subgroup indices.